# Create Python Namespace Without File Name

Tags: python, python-3.x, namespaces

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to figure out how to best organize my code. I'm planning on adding a few classes in their own files and I'd like to reference the classes without having to specify the file name. For example let's say I have a structure like this:

```
my_project/
└── module1/
    ├── A.py
    └── B.py
```

A.py

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

B.py

```
class B:
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Now let's say I want to reference class `A` in `B.py`. How can I make it so that `B.py` looks like this:

```
import A
class B:
    def foo(self):
        return A()
```

and not like this:

```
from a import A
class B:
    def foo(self):
        return A()
```

Essentially, I'd like to group classes into one namespace without having to put all of my classes into one file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you would need to correct the syntax of the class, your classes should be

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

and

```
from a import A

class B:
    def foo(self):
        return A()
```

Now the reason you need to do `from a import A` and not `import A` is because A is a class which lives in a python file .py, and you need to tell the interpreter where the class A is defined, otherwise the interpreter doesn't know where to find A

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the syntax bugs. Follow up to your answer, for the pandas library, I'm able to import DataFrame by adding `from pandas import DataFrame`, but based on the source code, it looks like I'd have to put `from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame`. Same thing goes for the `Series` class. How is pandas set up differently?

Comment: I haven't used pandas library, so unfortunately I cannot answer this for you. It is better you should ask a new question for it. Also please accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: @Hydrosis pandas imports specific submodules into its top level module as well. This is done by putting imports into the pandas/__init__.py file: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/9d66bdf1c6f252ba8a9f7b3298877d9c021a84c9/pandas/__init__.py#L47